# Fit sinusoidal models

Tags: matlab, noise, period, spectral

I have tried to fit following sinusoidal model by the following model, which means that deterministic model + white noise:

```
function [x]=generate(N,m,A3)
f1=100;
f2=200;
T=1/f1;
for t=0:N*T/m:N*T
    WN(t)=rand(1,t)*2-1;
    x(t)=20*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+30*cos(2*pi*f2*t)+A3*WN(t);
end;
```

But when I run using following command:

```
generate(100,10,40)
```

I got following error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in generate (line 6)
    WN(t)=rand(1,t)*2-1;
```

So what is wrong? As I know I can use two parameters for `rand` function right? What is problem here?

UPDATED:
that is what i have done for fixing it

```
function [ x]=generate(N,m,A3)
WN=[];
f1=100;
f2=200;
T=1/f1;
k=0;
for t=0:N*T/m:N*T
   % WN(k)=rand(1,1)*2-1;
   % x(k)=20*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+30*cos(2*pi*f2*t)+A3*WN(k);
    %k=k+1;
    WN=rand*2-1;
     disp(20*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+30*cos(2*pi*f2*t)+A3*WN);
end;
```

and result

```
 generate(1000,10,40)
   25.4143

   -1.4678

   66.9518

   -9.6293

   51.9928

   55.3843

   59.4956

   -3.2451

   21.9826

   10.7896

   54.0055
```

Comment: It would appear that at least one value of `t` is not a positive integer...

Comment: how it could be?t is changing from positive to positive

Comment: Why not print out the values of `t` and confirm that?

Comment: t is  not   integers,it is  real like  0.3  and so on

Comment: Then of course it won't work!  You can't index into an array/matrix with a non-integer value.

Comment: the same error,like this   Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in generate (line 7)
    WN(k)=rand(1,1)*2-1;

Comment: i have changed it into different  form.i will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it as follows:

```
function x = generate(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))';
wn = rand(length(t),1).*2 - 1;
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

rand(1,t) generates 1 by t matrix, to get a scalar value you can use rand(1,1)

Answer (score 1):

Note that sin and cos accept vector arguments, so there is no need for a for loop,

```
T = 1 / fs;
t = (0:N-1)' * T; 
WN = rand(N, 1) * 2; 
WN = WN - mean(WN); 
x = 20 * sin(2*pi*f1*t) + 30 * cos(2*pi*f2*t) + A3 * WN;
```

Additionally, your value for T should be 1 / sample rate, not 1 / f1 (unless you are sampling at this frequency, in which case you cannot expect to see the right results because your frequencies are BOTH above the Nyquist frequency of fs / 2, so there will be aliasing). Also, you should be subtracting the mean of the whole vector WN, not just blindly assuming that the mean is 0.5 (or 1, once it's been multiplied by 2).